# BAMT Email Alerts Setup

Tags: miner-configuration, bamt

I have BAMT running on my rig but I don't think the email alerts are working, possibly due to a bad config.

I would like to use Google's SMTP server if possible (or any other free SMTP provider) but Google's uses TLS, which isn't supported in the BAMT configs I believe, so if this isn't possible (and no other free SMTP servers are available), how would I go about setting up my own SMTP server on the rig?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stick with Google and use STunnel to avoid TLS**

There is a useful article describing how to get this to work here: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/mail-settings/oCwPE2o_oCM

The relevant excerpts are:

> You can use STunnel to allow non-SSL devices to connect.  STunnel
> should be run on a computer on your network that is up 24/7.  The
> network printers will connect to STunnel using non-SSL SMTP then
> STunnel will bridge the connection to Google Apps using an SSL
> connection.  STunnel can be downloaded at:
>
> http://www.stunnel.org/
>
> Your stunnel.conf file should look like:
>
> -- begin stunnel.conf --
>
> cert = stunnel.pem
>
> socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
>
> socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
>
> client = yes
>
> [pop3s]
>
> accept  = 110
>
> connect = pop.gmail.com:995
>
> [imaps]
>
> accept  = 143
>
> connect = imap.gmail.com:993
>
> [ssmtp]
>
> accept  = 25
>
> connect = smtp.gmail.com:465
>
> -- end stunnel.conf --

It's worth reading around the rest of the information on the site

**I tried STunnel and failed! What now?**

Try using the sneaky printer backdoor to Google's SMTP servers that avoids SSL. Instructions are here: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=176600

Relevant info is:

> If your device does not support SSL, connect to aspmx.l.google.com on port 25.
>
> You must configure an SPF record for your domain with the IP address
> of the device to ensure that recipients do not reject mail sent from
> it. You must also add this IP address to the Email Whitelist box in
> your Google Apps control panel.
>
> For example. if your sending device
> sends from 123.45.67.89, add that address to your SPF record without
> removing the Google Apps mail servers from the record: v=spf1
> ip4:123.45.67.89 include:_spf.google.com ~all

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming I can run STunnel on the same BAMT rig?

Comment: Give it a go and see how it works out. If it works well then provide some feedback so that others can take advantage too. You might find the printer backdoor method works better for your situation.